# R- how to reference many variables in multiple regression?

Tags: r, regression

If I have a large dataset (i.e. 500 column variables), how can I run a regression defining a large range of independent variables without explicitly writing the variable names in the code (i.e. lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6 ... x100) )?

Thanks.

Comment: `as.formula(paste0("y~", paste(paste0("x", 1:100), collapse = "+")))`

Comment: In some places a dot will do the trick. `~.` or `y~.`